# the argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

I can't put icon and text at the same time for floatbuttom?
The error in the title.

```
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Hello'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        body: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text("it's working, $name"),
                new FlatButton(onPressed:()=> onClick('test'), child: new Icon(Icons.accessibility),child : new Text('data'))
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: This can be locked now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe wrapping both children in either a row or column would solve your problem.
FlatButton can only take one widget as the child parameter.

```
FlatButton(                    
  onPressed:()=> onClick('test')}, 
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Icon(Icons.accessibility),
      new Text('data'),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Adding a Row widget to solve this problem is not neccesary. see my answer.

Comment: I agree @encubos, your solution is better. I upvoted your post.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is inside the `FlatButton` widget, you are using **child** attribute two times.

You can put ***text*** and ***icon***, this way:

```
FlatButton.icon(
      icon: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
      label: Text('data'),
      onPressed: () {
        //Code to execute when Button is clicked
      },
)
```